# VS Code Branching Snippet Completion Items Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

I am attempting to add Completion snippets to an extension I'm writing based on the completions sample ( https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/completions-sample ). I would like to have it branch complete. In my extension, **SET** is a keyword that then has possible params. Each param then has further params.

Ex: **SET FOO|BAR|BAS** where **SET FOO** can be **ON|OFF**, **SET BAR** is **1|2|3**, and **SET BAS** is **RED|BLUE**.

I've tried to do it with

```
            const SetCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('SET');
            SetCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('SET ${1|FOO,BAR,BAS|};');
```

And then Follow on with

```
            const SetFooCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('FOO');
            SetFooCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('FOO ${1|ON,OFF|};');

            const SetBarCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('BAR');
            SetBarCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('BAR ${1|1,2,3|};');

            const SetBasCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('BAS');
            SetBasCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('BAS ${1|RED,BLUE|};');
```

And this sort of works if I retrigger completion after the first item is inserted. I think there might be a better way. In my real world code, there are about 15 SET things that I can call on, and each one has different types of params. Some are ON|OFF, some are numbers, some strings. In the above snippets, SET BAR ON is invalid, since BAR is an integer and only FOO is ON|OFF so I don't want to provide all possible parameters to all SET statements. They should be specific to the SET command that resolves in the first completion.

Is this possible?

Edit: Fixed typos in sample code

Comment: In your CompletionItemProvider first only give a snippet for the first argument of SET, then when the user types a space you find the correct option snippet for the case that the user has chosen: `SET FOO ` or `SET BAR `, mind the space at the end of the test string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a long look at this trying to figure out what is going on and concluded that because your first snippet is a ***choice*** snippet that you will not be able to do it as simply as you would like.

Normally, if you used this

```js
const SetCompletion  = new vscode.CompletionItem('SET');
SetCompletion .insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('SET ${1|FOO,BAR,BAS|};');

SetCompletion.command = { command: 'editor.action.triggerSuggest', title: 'Re-trigger completions...' };
```

that `command` property would help you avoid having to manually re-trigger the suggestions for `FOO/BAR/BAS`.  But it doesn't work.  I am convinced that the `command` runs after the snippet is inserted but before it is completed.

You can see this if you use other commands like

```js
SetCompletion.command = { command: 'leaveSnippet', title: '...' };
```

In this case, you won't even get the choice presented because the `leaveSnippet` command has already run!

So it seems the simplest is this:

```js
const SetFooCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('SET FOO');
SetFooCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('SET FOO ${1|ON,OFF|};');

const SetBarCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('SET BAR');
SetBarCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('SET BAR ${1|1,2,3|};');

const SetBasCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('SET BAS');
SetBasCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('SET BAS ${1|RED,BLUE|};');
```

You would have to make a bunch of `SET xxx CompletionItems` but there would be no manually triggering of suggestions to complete.

[image: choice completions demo]

---

As an interesting aside (and more proof that the `command` is running **before** the snippet choice and thus of no use is code like this:

```js
const SetCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('SET');
SetCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}');

SetCompletion.command = { command: 'folder-operations.setCompletionCommand', title: 'Re-trigger completions...' };
```

With the command defined as

```js
const setCompletionHandler = vscode.commands.registerCommand('folder-operations.setCompletionCommand', async () => {
  await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.triggerSuggest');
  await vscode.commands.executeCommand('acceptSelectedSuggestion');
});
context.subscriptions.push(setCompletionHandler);
```

If you run that in a `FOO.<some extension>` or `BAR.<ext>` or `BAS.<ext>` it will work as expected.  The snippet fileNameBase is resolved before the `command` is run - the command just selects the top choice.

[image: snippet choice completions with a working command]

Comment: Appreciate your thoughts and testing. I have set it up with a bunch of SET commands like SET FOO and then the params and SET BAR and the params. It would be nice if I could do it where SET triggers the first completion and then the first param triggers the second completion but I guess it's not possible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works.

```javascript
const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.substr(0, position.character);
if (linePrefix.endsWith('SET')) {
  const setCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('SET', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet);
  setCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('SET ${1|FOO,BAR,BAS|};');
  const setFooCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('SET FOO', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet);
  setFooCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('SET FOO ${1|ON,OFF|};');
  const setBarCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('SET BAR', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet);
  setBarCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('SET BAR ${1|1,2,3|};');
  const setBasCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('SET BAS', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet);
  setBasCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('SET BAS ${1|RED,BLUE|};');
  return [setCompletion, setFooCompletion, setBarCompletion, setBasCompletion];
}
```

If you use `new vscode.CompletionItem('FOO');` it does not work. Looks like the label must match the last word of the line.

Also the line

```
blablaSET
```

does not give completion items. The `SET` must be a separate word. The completion items are created but are not shown.

---

Or you can try:

```js
const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.substr(0, position.character);
if (linePrefix.endsWith('SET')) {
  const setCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('SET', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet);
  setCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('SET ${1|FOO,BAR,BAS|}$0;');
  return [setCompletion];
}
if (linePrefix.endsWith('SET FOO')) {
  const setFooCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('FOO', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet);
  setFooCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('FOO ${1|ON,OFF|}');
  return [setFooCompletion];
}
if (linePrefix.endsWith('SET BAR')) {
  const setBarCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('BAR', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet);
  setBarCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('BAR ${1|1,2,3|}');
  return [setBarCompletion];
}
if (linePrefix.endsWith('SET BAS')) {
  const setBasCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('BAS', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet);
  setBasCompletion.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('BAS ${1|RED,BLUE|}');
  return [setBasCompletion];
}
```

You have to trigger the CompletionItems with `Ctrl+Space` after selecting one of the `SET` options. Look carefully when you leave the snippet (or double snippet) when using `TAB` (multiple times)